# how to get selectable to behave like radio button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, radio-button

I like the way that [this](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) can be styled, but I hate that user is able to select more than one item with this interface. Is there a way to either

1. Modify the selectable example to only allow for a single selection, or
2. Modify a standard radio button example such as [this](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio) to look more like the selectable example?

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything I can do to make my original post more clear, or to have it show more research effort.  Honestly, I have been working with these examples for the larger portion of the day and had gotten stumped.

Comment: You have to bear with it... many good questions get closed in this website because some users either don’t like it or don’t understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a similar UI using any html you want for buttons without needing to use `selectable`.

Example HTML:

```
<div>One: <input type="radio" name="rad"/> Two: <input type="radio" name="rad"/> Three: <input type="radio" name="rad"/></div>
<ul id="rad_buttons">
  <li>Radio 1</li> 
  <li>Radio 2</li>   
    <li>Radio 3</li>   
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var $radios=$('input[name="rad"]');
$('#rad_buttons li').click(function(){
  $('#rad_buttons li.active').removeClass('active')
  var $btn=$(this).addClass('active'), idx=$btn.index();
  $radios.eq( idx).prop('checked',true)
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aDFr8/

Comment: Thanks very much.  Looks like I need to read up on specifics of selectors and how to access DOM elements w/r/t jquery syntax.

Comment: Could you also include something about how to put the content that user has selected into a variable?

Comment: not sure what you mean, I assumed since you mentioned radios was a form and needed the radios themselves

Comment: I do, but I would like to know which was selected by user.  It doesn't have to return the text from the <li>, but even the id (0,1,2) would be good to know

Comment: return it to where?  the radio being checked is `$radios.eq( idx)` can retrieve it's value using `val()` and do what you want with it

Comment: AH!  thanks.  sorry for missing that.